# Android editing drawables

Tags: android, vector, bitmap

I am looking for a way to support a lot of screen devices without making tons of images.
Currently im using android-svg to use vector images. This works perfectly. But now i would like to process these images with inner shadows, drop shadows, gradient overlays etc.

There are functions in android to create gradientoverlays using canvas paint. But I can't think of a way to create inner shadows, drop shadows, etc.

Is there anyone who can give me an idea to do something like this? Maybe a library or "trick".

Answer (score 0):

Except for `TextView`, I'm not aware of any built-in drop shadow support for views or drawables.

The standard "trick" is to render an object twice: first slightly set off and overlaid with a shadow color, then again unchanged. This is not very efficient but it does the job. This is in fact what a maps `Overlay` does to drop item shadows (it will call `draw` twice: first with the `shadow` parameter set to true, then again set to false).

If you are targeting Honeycomb or newer, you could also try using [DragShadowBuilder](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.DragShadowBuilder.html). It's meant to be used for creating a shadow shape while dragging an item, but I imagine you can use it elsewhere, too. Or [look at the sources](https://github.com/android/platform_frameworks_base/blob/master/core/java/android/view/View.java) and go from there.